# Cracker Barrell Puzzle solver in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, puzzle

I am implementing a recursive solution to the [Cracker Barrel Puzzle](http://home.comcast.net/~danceguy/PegGame.html).

My recursive function returns a string representation of the state of the solved board and all the steps leading to that state.
At each stage in my recursive function, a valid gameboard is generated and the function is recursively called on the gameboard object.

My problem is: what do I need to return when there are no valid gameboard moves that can be made on the current gameboard object?  Currently this scenario is causing the function to crash.

Comment: You could return a null pointer, or an empty string - or anything else that you design.  The decision is all yours; welcome to the powers of being designer of your own program.

Comment: Do you have any code for us to see? It is hard to comment on design decisions when there is no design to critique.

Comment: I would advise that you expand your question because you're not providing enough information for anyone to realistically help you. This usually leads to a protracted and frustrating round of requests in the comments for more information by other users who **really do want to help you**. For example, include in the question: code snippets/samples, the API you're using, stack traces, screen shots etc. When you've done this, flag to have your question re-opened. Please also take the time to [read this](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well you have the problem of determining the base case. For mathematical recursive functions, the base case is trivial, like `F(0)` for the case of **Fibonacci Numbers**.

Although, I am not familiar with that game or your exact implementation, if you reach a state when no more recursive call would arise, return a `Base value`. For numbers, it would be the base value, for `strings` a `zero` length string. For the case of Gameboard, use a Default state for every cell to indicate that this is a base case and handle that appropriately on the return.

Comment: i am currently returning an empty string but the puzzle then will not be solved, i need a way to continue the recursion or maybe its just not possible to implement this recursively

Comment: @sola: I am pretty much sure it can be solved recursively(provided there isn't any resource constraints). It's a well known fact in CS that all problems are solvable recursively. What you have to do is decide how to handle this base case. As " Jonathan Leffler" said, you have full power over that.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to implement recursive functions. Without any hits as to how you have decided to go (you have hinted that you are returning the game state in a string... std::string?), maybe you simply need an if statement:

```
std::string recursive_game(std::string &populate)
{
    if (...game is finished...) {
        ...
        return populate;
    } else {
        ...
        return recursive_game(populate);
    } 
}

int main()
{
    std::string completed_game;

    recursive_game(completed_game);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems you have to test your return value and throw an exception in case you can't return a correct value.

Comment: exceptions are hardly the best solution for ending a program which is recursive by design. bad.

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding a sanity check function

```
void main ()
{
    bool validMovesAvailable =true;
    string currentMoves;  
    do
    {
        currentMoves = doNextMove (currentMoves); //your current function
        validMovesAvailable = checkAnyMoreMoves (currentMoves); //sanity check function

    }while (validMovesAvailable);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You return the *number of pegs left on the board*. This is the score of the game.